# Using knockout binding with objects containing an array of objects

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of objects, and each object contains another array of objects. This array is dynamic and may change often.  There is not a set number of Awards in the AwardArry:

```
Name: Karen
AwardArray:  
   AwardName: BestDressed
   RecievedNoTimes: 3

   AwardName: MostImproved
   RecievedNoTimes: 5
Name: Sam
  AwardArray:
     AwardName: Funniest
     Received:  3

     AwardName: LikelyToSucceed
     Receieved: 8
```

I would like to bind this to a sortable table using knockout:

```
Name    Best Dressed     Most Improved     Funniest    Likely To Succeed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Karen       3                 5              0               0
Sam         2                 0              3               8
```

Is there anyway to do this in Knockout?

What I've tried:
Controller:
    personVM.rows = {call to database to get rows}

Javascript:
    ajax call to get data for view model

View:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">
              <a href="#" data-orderby="name" data-bind="click: setOrderBy">Name</a></th>

         <th data-bind="foreach: rows.AwardArray">               
             <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
         </th>
              </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: rows">
              <tr><td><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Name shows up fine so my view model is populated, however the column names do not show up.  I have no idea how to put the data in as the knockout website talks about binding an array, not an array with an array.  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: there are several. have you tried anything or visited the knockoutjs.com website and viewed the examples/documentation?

Comment: yes i added to my answer

Comment: you'll probably want to re-package your data that is bound to the table so you can ensure that the awards columns are in the proper order if you aren't already

Comment: Your post still reads more like a (rather large and somewhat vague / low on details) to do, as opposed to a practical code question. When including code in your question, please check "[mcve]" for guidance.